# Creating Observer in RxJS (TypeScript) 5.0 that does not bind to `this`

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I am working in an NG2 app using TypeScript and want to create an observable around a call to Amazon AWS SDK.

```
var foo =  Observable.create( (observer) => {
  this.s3.upload({
    Key: "value"
  }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return
    }
    observer.next(data)
  });
})
```

Unfortunately, `this` is now bound to the Observable.  How should I approach this if I want `this` to remain bound to the parent class?

Comment: Simple (I think), don't use the arrow operator. Just create some old-fashioned anonymous javascript functions. Then bind `this` to some variable and use that variable if you need access.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes that works, but I was hoping for a solution that did not involve the hack.  Arrow function works as well if I create a proxy variable for `this`

Comment: Why do you think it's a "hack?" The arrow operator is designed to be bound to `this`. That solves a problem which you have the exact opposite of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap the observer function and bind your outside `this` to it:

```
var foo = Observable.create((function(observer) {
  this.s3.upload({
    Key: "value"
  }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return
    }
    observer.next(data)
  });
}).bind(this));
```

It's important to make sure the wrapped function is a classic function and not an arrow function, or `this` within the function will end up being the `window`.